# Can I use Tufte-Latex book template to write a commercial book?

Tags: book-design, books

I am writing a commercial book. I wonder if I can use [Tufte-Latex template](https://tufte-latex.github.io/tufte-latex/) for a commercial book. How should I give due credit to the template authors?

Moreover, is there a better and modern looking latex book template? My book has programming code and many figures.

[Edit following comments]

By better looking, I mean to use a design like 'Head First ' books (ex: Head First Java). The book is full of illustrations and figures and fun to read.

Comment: The template says it is released in Apache License 2.0. Wikipedia says that I can use the license for commercial use as long as my book does NOT endorse Apache. I want to make sure if anybody has idea about its proper usage and giving due credits. Thanks.

Comment: If you could specify the features you are looking for, we could help you find "modern" equivalents in other classes as well.

Comment: If you ask about giving credits consider using a colophon for that. For anything else you should define your aims (what you mean with better/modern looking).

Comment: @user124577 Thanks. By better looking, I mean to use a design like 'Head First ' books (ex: Head First Java). The book is full of illustrations and figures and fun to read. Not exactly that, but is there a latex template for such kind of books?

Comment: Note that we CANNOT tell you whether it is OK to use the template or not. If you cannot tell this from the licence, you must ask a lawyer or your publisher or whoever. Legal issues are strictly off-topic. Can you please edit your question to focus it on the TeXnical aspects?

Comment: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really about (La)TeX but a question about licensing and allowed use. When it comes back to LaTeX content, it could be re-opened (or simply a new question can be created).